# Output score , class, id and BOXES Extraction using TensorFlow object detection

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51213290/output-score-class-and-id-extraction-using-tensorflow-object-detection). 
Mine is;
Let us assume that there is one picture that contains 3 cats ,2 dogs and 1 bird.
After detection of whole object how could we get the xmin ymin xmax ymax values of separated 6 object.

Answer (score 0):

After these lines

```
    (boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run(
          [boxes, scores, classes, num_detections],
          feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
```

you can retrieve the information you need looking into

```
    boxes, scores, classes, num_detections
```

Answer (score 0):

in Python it looks like

```
    # this loop Counting the Objects found from highest to lowest %, Default is 100Results. Only > x% get counted
        scores = output_dict['detection_scores'] as example
        boxes = output_dict['detection_boxes'] as example
        classes = output_dict['detection_classes'] as example
        count=0  
        xmin=[]
        xmax=[]
        ymin=[]
        ymax=[] 
        classlist=[]         
        for s in range (100):
            if scores is None or scores [s] > 0.5:
                count = count + 1
        for i in range (count):
            position = np.squeeze(boxes[0][i])
            (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax) = (position[1]*im_width, position[3]*im_width, position[0]*im_height, position[2]*im_height)
        xmin.append(xmin)
        xmax.append(xmax)
        ymin.append(ymin)
        ymax.append(ymax)
        classlist.append(classes[i])
```

The Lists are sorted from Highest to lowest Score.
Sorry for the beginner code im new to this.